# Websphere deployment - MapModulesToServers

Tags: websphere

Apologies if this has been asked previously but I have the following code in my Props file.

```
#
# Properties
#
taskName=MapModulesToServers
  row0={module uri server ModuleVersion moduletype moduletypeDisplay} # readonly
  row1={"MyApplication" MyApplication.war,WEB-INF/web.xml WebSphere:cell=!{cellName},node=!{nodeName},server=!{webserverName} 
  + WebSphere:cell=!{cellName},node=!{nodeName},server=!{httpserverName} 23 moduletype.web "Web Module"}
```

Now I am trying to get the WAR file mapped to both the WebServer and the HTTPServer, both of which are up and running. At present the process only maps to the Web server and we are forced to map to both manually after deployment, which defeats the aim of auto deployment a little.
Can any tell me what is wrong in the script segment please.

thanks in advance

Kev

Comment: I'm speculating a bit here. The content of row0 represents columns, and the third one is server. What happens if you create a row2 variable, with server column set to HTTPServer and the remaining columns the same as row1?

Comment: Hi, I will try that asap and let you know.